# Loop with undefined number of iterations

Tags: java, loops

I have a logic problem. User is allowed to add any number of fields to the form. Upon form submission, I need to collect the values of all the fields and store them in an ArrayList. The problem is that I don't know whether there will be only 1 field in the form, or 500.

The way I differentiate individual form fields is by adding index number to their name, so in a form there are fields with name="field1", name="field2" etc.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
for (int i = 1; i < number of fields; i++) {
    while (request.getParameter("field" + Integer.toString(i)) != null) {
        Add to ArrayList
    }
}
```

How can I find the number of fields? Or maybe there is another solution to this problem?

Comment: How are you storing the fields in the form? Surely the object which is storing the fields must know how many there are, or at least know how to iterate over the fields.

Comment: @Mankarse exactly, this looks like an design flaw to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
int i=0;

while (request.getParameter("field" + Integer.toString(i)) != null) {

    // Add to ArrayList

    i++; // very important, don't forget this one
}

// i is the count of fields at this point
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be OK:

```
i=1;

while (request.getParameter("field" + Integer.toString(i)) != null) {
        //Add to ArrayList
        i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 types of loops in java.

1. for loop - used when you know exactly how many entries you have to iterate over.
2. while loop - used when you have no idea how many, could be 0 - 500
3. a do while - used when it will have to run at least once and any number after that.

Sounds like you need to figure out a way to check if a field exists and construct either a while or do while depending whether they are going to be able to enter 0 or not

Comment: A for loop doesn't need to know how many entries there are. It just needs a stop condition: `for (int i = 0; request.getParameter("field" + i) != null; i++) {...}`

Comment: yes you can actually do this but it is a well understood java design principle not a physical restriction. This is how most courses / books will explain it as it makes more sense and gives a good use case example of when to use each one. Also most forums will give this answer, example: http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?threadid=152488

Comment: That's not at all a well understood Java design principle. The second part of the for loop is the termination condition, which, if present, must be a boolean. BTW, The official Java tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) doesn't explain it in terms of a number of elements. Nor does the JLS (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14)

Comment: Thats how I was thought in college by multiple lecturers all with long careers behind them, also how it was described in the 2 java books we looked at and the 4 general programming provincials / practises described it. Its just he easiest way to describe it as most people when there starting out can't understand when to use one over the other

Comment: Just because it's easy to understand doesn't make it true. Before the enhanced for loop was introduced, most of the for loops looked like this: `for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {`. There's absolutely no notion of a known number of elements here.

Comment: Typing well structured code and including comments isn't a requirement but we are all thought those are good practises and (well try) to stick by them. Yes but thats not how there used anymore and therefore has no bearing on his question. I felt the question was about fairly basic aspects of java and could do with an easy explanation of what to use and when. I felt giving him an idea to help him from here on was more useful that quoting java docs, which is how most lecturers / books teach programming

Comment: Your good practice is not a good practice at all. Using a while loop instead of a for loop each time you don't know the number of elements leads to variables which have a wider scope than necessary. And that is actually a bad practice. And it's not justified at all since a for loop can cope with an undetermined number of elements as well as a while loop. Every while loop can be expressed with a for loop by not giving any initialization and update statement.

Comment: ok well thats your opinion, i tried to help this guy, all you've done is criticize my answer and not offered anything to help him. I'm gonna leave this at agree to disagree

Comment: The other answers are already good enough, and I voted for one of them. Reducing variable scope as much as possible is not just my opinion. Or do you like using global variables for everything?

Comment: a single int above a while loop instead of in the definition of a for loop is a bit of an exaggeration to say using global variables for everything. Using a while loop doesn't mean having a global variable, it leaves it 1 level higher than the loop and when you don't know the number is actually very useful later on as generally u'll need it more than once. helping someone understand programming verses the smallest increase of scope possible, ill go for teaching thanks. Just FYI the only answer with votes uses a while with a supposedly "global variable"

Comment: Although I voted for this answer, it should use the for loop I typed above, IMHO. The `i` variable is not needed at all after the loop, since the list has a `size()` method. I don't remember having used the value of the index after a loop once in the last 10 years of professional programming in Java. Of course my "global variables for everything" statement was an exaggeration, to help you understand my point about reducing the scope. BTW, how do you think I earned my 72000 repoutation points, if not by helping others?

Answer (score 0):

You can use request.getParameterNames() and cycle through the elements

```
for(Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames();
 e.hasMoreElements(); ){
                String parameterName = (String)e.nextElement();
             //Your code logic with the parameter.

}
```

This is a more efficient logic as you dont need to calculate the number of parameters first and then add to the `ArrayList`. and you dont need to play with `null` and NPEs

Answer (score 0):

Your `request` object should have useful methods for that such as `getParameterNames` which enumerates `String`s, or `getParameterMap` which is self-explanatory. Both of these can be used to set up a loop around all parameters, regardless of their count.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
  String parameterName = parameterNames.nextElement();
  if (parameterName.startsWith("field")) {
    Add request.getParameter(parameterName) to ArrayList
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getParameterValues() to get all values to do this you have to be sure that all your fields in page should have the same name . like this

```
<input type="text" name="field" id="field1"/>
<input type="text" name="field" id="field2"/>
<input type="text" name="field" id="field3"/>
<input type="text" name="field" id="field4"/>
```

and at server side you can write like this

```
String[] arrFields  = request.getParameterValues("field");
for(String field: arrField)
{
      // put the field into the arraylist.
}
```